Empty fields in Profile page in bottomnavigation bar Android Studio Firebase
Doesn't display data from firebase and shows empty fields instead of values ​​from database. I tried changing the intent values, but it didn't help. I also tried to rewrite showuserdata and that didn’t help either.
Opposite the Name, email, username, password fields there should be values from Firebase, everything is displayed correctly there, but is not transferred to the fields
enter image description here
ProfileActivity:
package com.example.healthsport;

import android.os.Bundle;


import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;


import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;


public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView profileName, profileEmail, profileUsername, profilePassword;
    TextView titleName, titleUsername;
    Button editProfile;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigation);
        bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.profile);

        bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(item -> {
            int itemId = item.getItemId();
            if (itemId == R.id.home) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
                finish();
                return true;
            } else return itemId == R.id.profile;
        });

        profileName = findViewById(R.id.profileName);
        profileEmail = findViewById(R.id.profileEmail);
        profileUsername = findViewById(R.id.profileUsername);
        profilePassword = findViewById(R.id.profilePassword);
        titleName = findViewById(R.id.titleName);
        titleUsername = findViewById(R.id.titleUsername);

        showAllUserData();
    }

    public void showAllUserData(){
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String nameUser = intent.getStringExtra("name");
        String emailUser = intent.getStringExtra("email");
        String usernameUser = intent.getStringExtra("username");
        String passwordUser = intent.getStringExtra("password");
        titleName.setText(nameUser);
        titleUsername.setText(usernameUser);
        profileName.setText(nameUser);
        profileEmail.setText(emailUser);
        profileUsername.setText(usernameUser);
        profilePassword.setText(passwordUser);
    }
}

LoginActivity:
package com.example.healthsport;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import java.util.Objects;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText loginUsername, loginPassword;
    Button loginButton;
    TextView signupRedirectText;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        loginUsername = findViewById(R.id.login_username);
        loginPassword = findViewById(R.id.login_password);
        loginButton = findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        signupRedirectText = findViewById(R.id.signupRedirectText);
        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (!validateUsername() | !validatePassword()) {
                } else {
                    checkUser();
                }
            }
        });
        signupRedirectText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SignupActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
    public Boolean validateUsername() {
        String val = loginUsername.getText().toString();
        if (val.isEmpty()) {
            loginUsername.setError("Username cannot be empty");
            return false;
        } else {
            loginUsername.setError(null);
            return true;
        }
    }
    public Boolean validatePassword(){
        String val = loginPassword.getText().toString();
        if (val.isEmpty()) {
            loginPassword.setError("Password cannot be empty");
            return false;
        } else {
            loginPassword.setError(null);
            return true;
        }
    }
    public void checkUser(){
        String userUsername = loginUsername.getText().toString().trim();
        String userPassword = loginPassword.getText().toString().trim();
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
        Query checkUserDatabase = reference.orderByChild("username").equalTo(userUsername);
        checkUserDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()){
                    loginUsername.setError(null);
                    String passwordFromDB = snapshot.child(userUsername).child("password").getValue(String.class);
                    if (passwordFromDB.equals(userPassword)) {
                        loginUsername.setError(null);
                        String nameFromDB = snapshot.child(userUsername).child("name").getValue(String.class);
                        String emailFromDB = snapshot.child(userUsername).child("email").getValue(String.class);
                        String usernameFromDB = snapshot.child(userUsername).child("username").getValue(String.class);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("name", nameFromDB);
                        intent.putExtra("email", emailFromDB);
                        intent.putExtra("username", usernameFromDB);
                        intent.putExtra("password", passwordFromDB);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        loginPassword.setError("Invalid Credentials");
                        loginPassword.requestFocus();
                    }
                } else {
                    loginUsername.setError("User does not exist");
                    loginUsername.requestFocus();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });

    }
}

SignupActivity:
package com.example.healthsport;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;



public class SignupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText signupName, signupUsername, signupEmail, signupPassword;
    TextView loginRedirectText;
    Button signupButton;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference reference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);

        signupName = findViewById(R.id.signup_name);
        signupEmail = findViewById(R.id.signup_email);
        signupUsername = findViewById(R.id.signup_username);
        signupPassword = findViewById(R.id.signup_password);
        loginRedirectText = findViewById(R.id.loginRedirectText);
        signupButton = findViewById(R.id.signup_button);
        signupButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                reference = database.getReference("users");
                String name = signupName.getText().toString();
                String email = signupEmail.getText().toString();
                String username = signupUsername.getText().toString();
                String password = signupPassword.getText().toString();
                HelperClass helperClass = new HelperClass(name, email, username, password);
                reference.child(username).setValue(helperClass);
                Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "You have signup successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(SignupActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        loginRedirectText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SignupActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    }



package com.example.healthsport;

public class HelperClass {

        String name, email, username, password;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }

        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }

        public void setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }

        public HelperClass(String name, String email, String username, String password) {
            this.name = name;
            this.email = email;
            this.username = username;
            this.password = password;
        }

        public HelperClass() {
        }
    }



i don`t know what a problem :(

it could have planty of reasons, I suggest that you see how you can debug your app using debug mode, https://developer.android.com/studio/debug
and put some breakpoint all around your app to see what is going on exactly...

Welcome to SO. That's a lot of code for us to parse and the question doesn't include any troubleshooting to narrow down the section of code that's not working. Please perform troubleshooting by stepping through the code line by line, examining the flow and vars along the way until you find something unexpected. Then include your findings in your question - what line isn't working? Where does the code start to fail?

If you encounter problems, it's best to create a MCVE when posting a question. You posted more than 300 (three hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way, you increase your chances of being helped. Please take a moment and read how to ask a question. Please respond using @AlexMamo
